# elementary OS is taking too much time to start

Tags: release-juno, updates

I just updated the operational system with the updates released, 1h ago i think, and then when i restarted the laptop, and did the login i had to wait more the 1 minute (maybe 2 minutes) to access my screen, it was just a black screen. It took to much time to start.
Such thing happened to anyone else.

Comment: Yes, I had the same problem on HP Pavilion with GeForce GTX 1050 Mobile. I did many restarts with almost no difference, probably 1 of 5 was ok, but the others was like more than a minute of black screen with active mouse pointer only, sometimes even mouse freezes. I was messing with the system before the update so I decided that this is the reason. Because of that I don't say that it will solve your problem, but everything was fixed (I had a problem returning from suspend also) when I have installed the Nvidia driver (`sudo ubuntu-drivers autoinstall`). Now everything works nice and smooth.